# Fetching non-null values with column names in SQL

Tags: sql

My table - students is of the form

```
               Student    Subject1   Subject2
               A          123         1
               B                      4
               C          122
```

I want to fetch all the non-empty records of a Student along with column names
Note:Only non-empty records should be displayed

so when I query for student A I should get

```
          Subject1 123               
          Subject2 1
```

when I query for student B I should get

```
          Subject2 4
```

when I query for student C I should get 
              Subject1 122

I want to generate the column names dynamically.
Thanks for the help!

Comment: what is your RDBMS? sqlserver? mysql? oracle? what version?

Comment: Poor table design. You should have one row per subject. If you can't change the db design, at least create a view that UNION ALL's the subject columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This can be done as follows -

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
(
    WITH A AS
    (
        SELECT 'A' AS STUDENT,  123 AS SUBJECT1, 1 AS SUBJECT2 FROM DUAL
        UNION
        SELECT 'B' AS STUDENT,  NULL AS SUBJECT1, 4 AS SUBJECT2 FROM DUAL
        UNION
        SELECT 'C' AS STUDENT,  122 AS SUBJECT1, NULL AS SUBJECT2 FROM DUAL
    )
    SELECT * 
    FROM 
        A
    UNPIVOT 
        (
            MARKS FOR SUBJECT IN (SUBJECT1, SUBJECT2)
        )
) 
WHERE 
    STUDENT = 'A';
```

> Output -

```
STUDENT,SUBJECT,MARKS
A,SUBJECT1,123
A,SUBJECT2,1
```